# How to get from UK to Tunisia

Tags: air-travel, uk, routes, tunisia

I am something of a Noob when it comes to travelling however, personal affairs with a friend of mine requires me to try and find a way out to Sousse.

I am however, having really bad luck at finding a decent way out. I know the UK has stopped direct flights to Tunisia for the most part but even going from other airports like Paris presents itself with maybe one flight every 2 days.

So, what is a good way to go from the UK to Sousse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nearest airport to Sousse is Monastir, with the airport and Sousse being connected by the Sahel Metro suburban train.

Tunisair has direct flights from Brussels, Lyon, Marseille and Paris, with flights from Paris also operated by Nouvelair and Transavia France.

Your best bet is [Skyscanner](https://www.skyscanner.net/), where you can search for flights from your UK airport of choice to Monastir. You will usually get the cheapest possible fares, with various booking sites being included in the calculation.

Comment: It seems it might actually be easier to go Tunis and then take something down to Sousse

Comment: @Sammaye Well, at least Tunisair does have direct flights to Tunis from London-Heathrow and London-Gatwick. It is, however, 150 km from Sousse, and I have no idea about the various transport options between the cities

Comment: Indeed, I might be forced to just persuade a taxi to go all the way (probably at a premium)

Comment: @Sammaye Here's some info on trains http://www.seat61.com/Tunisia2.htm#Gabès